# Fluent Design in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, code-snippets, fluent-design

Fluent design by Microsoft are basically guidelines to design apps but they also include code snippets and tools on how to achieve them in UWP apps. A lot of tools and snippets are available for UWP but I cannot find anything for Xamarin.Forms.

How can Fluent design be implemented in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: you want to use fluent design in xamarin forms or do you want to understand designing in xamarin forms?

Comment: It seems like a request for documentation or tutorials, which is defined as off-topic for SO: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: @G.hakim I want to use fluent design in xamarin forms but there are no code snippets or tools available for that.

Comment: Well because i am pretty sure its not possible

Answer (score 0):

In my shop we use XAML for UI, you may have some luck writing fluent methods for C# UI code but I find the declarative nature of XAML to be fairly intuitive and easiest to use.

That being said you may want to explore Reactive UI for ViewModels. It's fluent in design right out of the box.

https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/platform/xamarin-forms

```
var canExecute = this.WhenAnyValue(
    x => x.UserName, x => x.Password,
    (userName, password) => 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password));

LoadCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(LogOnAsync, canExecute);

LoadCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(error => { });
```

Comment: He's talking about Fluent Design Guidelines, not about ReactiveUI fluent extensions.